# How to connect existing droplet to Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

Background:
I used LF to create a droplet on digitalocean where I have multiple sites configured. I recently had to move the droplet to a different digitalocean data center. By "move the droplet" I mean that I created a snapshot and then created a new droplet in the other data center using that image. Both droplets are up and running and I've changed DNS mappings accordingly to point to the new server. Everything is working as expected.

Problem I'm trying to solve:
The only issue is Laravel Forge is connected to the old droplet and not the new one. I know I can archive the old one, and I'll destroy the old droplet at some point. Is there a way to connect Laravel Forge to the new droplet so I can manage it via the LF interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the forge display, if you edit/manage the server, goto the `Meta` tab and update the IP address. This should then make forge connect to the new droplet and forget about the old one.

[image: Laravel forge meta data fields]

You can then go back to your list of servers and test the connection by clicking the refresh icon under the `connection` column in the table.

[image: Laravel forge test connection]

Comment: My only complaint with Laravel Forge is that it still shows the old data center in the server details bar at the top. But I can live with that.

Comment: You need to restart your server. :)

Comment: As far as I know, updating meta data does not actually change anything at all about the server connection. It simply changes what's displayed for the public/private IP address, but won't affect the actual server itself.